# In Responsive Website if we adjust the font size based on screen resolution. Is it a good practice?

Tags: css

Would like to know if adjusting the font size of the element on the webpage based on windows size is a bad or good in Responsive web designing.i.e. using http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/ for example.

There seems to be lot of confusion this area because if we have a paragraph which has 5 lines when shown on 1024px screen can become two line in 1600px screen which will result lot of space between elements and which make the screen elements scattered.

Please guide the right approach be followed.

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: It is good practice to make your responsive website appear reasonable at all screen resolutions. If you need to adjust the font size to do so, then do that. There is no single correct way of doing it. Every website is different.

Comment: Sometime we are too much into the "CSS-magic-overcomplicated-world" and forgot the most simple things... at the very beginning of "responsiveness era" i was used to `font-size:medium|small|large|x-large|...` worked like a sharm, and still does i guess.